Parachute extension when it is connected to a moving Dynamics Cart
So, I was trying to see the effect of the surface area of the parachute on the velocity of a cart(with a parachute horizontally attached to it) after it passes a certain distance. It is supposed to be accelerated by a spring and the issue I'm facing is that the parachute isn't extending. I've tried varying the surface area, the length of the threads. I've even added a tiny piece to sort of elevate the parachute but still there's no extension. If anyone has faced this sort of issue before could you please let me know how I fix this?
